# Cannot open W3SVC service on computer '.'

Tags: c#, iis

I have written below code to check the status of the iis .  But I get the error as "Cannot open W3SVC service on computer '.' "

```
 ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("W3SVC");

                            if (controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                            {
                                CommonCalls.WriteLog("ISS status : Running " ;
                            }
```

It works fine in my local environment . But when the code moved to the production (live) environment , i get this error . I looked around the web and found some probable solutions about turning on or off windows features. Dat didnt help .   Can anyone help ?

Comment: Seems you have not enough permission on target machine.

Comment: Does your code is running with Admin rights on the remote computer?